# How to sort prices based low to high and high to low?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP, I have a table with several prices in columns, I want to add a drop down to sort prices in the table only based on adult price from low to high and high to low.

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php echo $row->tour_adult_price." ".$currSign ; ?>
```

and drop down:

```
    <option value="price-asc">By Price: Lowest to Highest</option>
    <option value="price-desc">By Price: Highest to Lowest</option>
```

what should I add that it will be sorted based on drop down menu ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better do your sort using mysql query itself.

Example

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY ASC|DESC
```

ASC -> Ascending

DESC -> Descending

So add your sort options in HTML as below

```
<select name='sort'>
    <option value='ASC'> Price Low to High </option>
    <option value='DESC'> Price High to Low </option>
</select>
```

Finally, Query Example:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY column '.$_REQUEST['sort'];
```

Note: When user choose sort option you may need to reload or submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could do query based on `$_GET` param. If `$_GET['param'] == 'desc'` then do query `ORDER BY column DESC` else if `$_GET['param'] == 'asc'` do `ORDER BY column ASC` I think.